# javascript - How to autofill ID field based on Name that input in other textfield?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two Textfields :

```
<form action="input.php" method="post">
  <!--First Field-->
  <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="" />
  <!--Second Field-->
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
</form>
```

Database content :

```
|ID_STAFF|NAME_STAFF|
|-------------------|
|    1   |  Edward  |
```

So, when I input staff name in second field , automatically staff ID will filled in first field.

Example :

```
Second Field : Edward
First Field  : 1
```

I have use this code, but It only duplicate what I typed in second field

```
$(function(){
 $("#name").keypress(function(){
 $("#id").val($(this).val());
 });
});
```

So, what is javascript code that I have to make? Thank You Master :D

Comment: Please provide more information about what you want to achieve. What does this "id" depend on? How is it related to the name? where does the data come from? That whole question doesn't make any sense =/

Comment: either you preload json values of all the values of database content (if its not many), or the other way is ajax on keyup

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that.

```
$(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("name") + "_staff");       
    });
});
```